# What are some solid solutions for "site settings" - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

So, on several projects that I've worked with there is the ever-present problem of "Settings".

I'm talking about settings that are specific to the "product".

Like:

- Payment API URL - one setting for the test/stage environment and one for production.
- Customer service email address - same, one for stage/test one for prod.

Solutions I've seen used:

- Web.config - With the new "transforms" stuff it's much better but once you have a pretty large list of settings, that even gets messy
- Stored in the database - Once you get a large set that are used all over the place, you start getting pretty chatty with the DB
- Stored in the DB, but cached in the APP - If you work with a large server farm, you have to reboot everything when a single setting changes.

Is anyone aware of a better solution - whether that is a "plug in" or nuget package or commercial product or even a different architectural approach that someone has had success with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about a cache, such as point 3, that busts whenever your settings table changes? The cache could poll for changes and bust when they happen. That's how i typically do it. That or absolute expiration of 15 minutes... Still good value cache-wise.